# visual studio - How to move my code from an old web application template to a new empty web application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

When i started learning asp.net, i created a new project in visual studio but it wasn't empty and it seems to be a template which has Site.master, Default.aspx, Global.asax... and even a database too. i started writing code in Default.aspx.

While proceeding with coding i now have errors when i try to access data from and to controls such as `'textbox3' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

So i need to start a new project (empty this time) and move my code from old project to new empty project.

**Question**

How can i accomplish that? What code do i have to take from old project? must i have a new Site.master page too, or should i take any code from it such as `<form runat="server">` for example?

- I only need to transfer Default.aspx, its code-behind, and Connection.vb (a
  class that i created).

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178866/txtname-is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level

Comment: regarding that link about the error, i looked it up before but it didn't help so that's why i thought to move my code to a new empty project. thanks anyway IrishChieftain.

Comment: May not be necessary to create a new project to fix this...

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing the the textbox name to match that in the designer file and the errors should go away. Failing that, try re-creating Default.aspx, then delete the old copy.

Comment: Yes they have the same name. but thanks anyway i guess i have to recreate the project in case there's any conflict somewhere nevertheless i'm not sure what to add from old project, if master page and else...

Comment: Just re-create everything the same ;-)

Comment: i will move the codes i added to not an empty project the same as before if that's what you mentioned, it may fix the error! Thanks anyway IrishChieftain.

Comment: no that didn't work, same error when i recreate with ASP.NET Website. however new errors occur when i try to recreating with an ASP.NET Empty Website. if i only know how to re-create with an empty website as my main question says that might help me to know what code might be conflicting :(

Comment: Just create a new project and add to id gradually. Delete default page and start by creating the master page. Then create a new Default page, etc.

Comment: if i want to start anew that's a problem since i'm not sure what i need to write/keep in a Site.master page, so that was my main question. thanks anyway for trying to help IrishChieftain.