# How to calculate the sum of all the textboxes on clientside?

Tags: asp.net, parsing, c#-4.0, null

I've to show the sum of all the textboxes in an another textbox, this is to be done on server side.

The values in the textbox might be any integer or a null value.

I've set the 'autopostback' property of the textboxes to true.

```
    private void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text)))
        {
            TextBox8.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text)).ToString();
        } 

    }
```

after adding this to the cs file, I tried running the page and was shown this compiler error

```
     'WebApplication1.c_fail.TextBox2_TextChanged(object, System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
       ontextchanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

If somebody can provide a solution to this error or just give a correct piece of code to workout with the situation. The piece of code you provide should also work if there is/are  null values in the textbox.

Comment: For Client side, you have to use javascript.

Comment: @Moniecorleone any solutions for the server side then? and the result should be produced in another text box.

Comment: Please check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178866/txtname-is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level this may be a cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do this calcs on client-side you must not declare the `TextBox` with `autopostback = true` and you need to do your issue using client side scripting (eg JavaScript) not C# code that is going to be executed from server side.

Comment: Please, try to explain a little better. Do you want to this on client-side or in server-side?

Comment: I don't know what developing level of ASP.NET do you have, but it's important that you well-know the life cycle of ASP pages and also the feature of `autopostback` atribute (for TextBox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback(v=vs.80).aspx). If you need **instant** updates of the textboxes, you can't do it from code behind (server-side).

Comment: earlier I dint knew the difference. So please forgive me for my ignorance and provide some solution for the server side.

Comment: @adrinpanico why not? if I use onTextChange event, and update the textbox values?

Comment: Please, research about the ASP's life cycle. The TextChange method raises only if you set the TextBox as AutoPostBack and **just before** press enter or tab. This behavior means sending the results to the server, do your logic, and resending the rendered page to the client. If that is enough for you, then that is your choice. If you want really instant updates, you need to use client-side scripting.

Answer (score -1):

To do it on client side you have to use Javascript autopostback means you are using server-side code

Comment: thanks.. I got that and have done the editing with the post. Any solutions for this error or the situation?