# Get the client id of a control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my web page i want to access the client id of control in the $(document).ready function,

below is the code,,

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgrStakeholders" runat="server" >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Literal ID="lit1" runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                          <telerik:RadComboBox ID="combo1" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                         <telerik:RadComboBox ID="combo11" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>  
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                <asp:TemplateColumn >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Literal ID="lit2" runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>

                                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="combo3" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>

                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>                                        
                                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="combo4" EnableLoadOnDemand="true"  
                                            Width="150px" Height="150px" Filter="Contains" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>                                               
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>

                                <asp:TemplateColumn >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Literal ID="lit54" runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt11" runat="server" Width="160px" />
                                        <asp:ListBox ID="lstNo" runat="server" DisplayMode="LinkButton"
                                            Style="display: none; position: absolute; margin: 2px; width: 210px" />
                                        <input type="button" id="btnNo" style="width: 10px;
                                            vertical-align: middle; height: 23px; margin-left: -3px; border-style: solid;
                                            border-width: thin; border-color: #7F9DB9; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-image: url(../../../Images/dropdownarrow.bmp);
                                            background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;" />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt12" runat="server" Width="160px" />
                                        <asp:ListBox ID="lstNo1" runat="server" DisplayMode="LinkButton"
                                            Style="display: none; position: absolute; margin: 2px; width: 210px;" />
                                        <input type="button" id="btnNo1" style="width: 10px;
                                            vertical-align: middle; height: 23px; margin-left: -3px; border-style: solid;
                                            border-width: thin; border-color: #7F9DB9; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-image: url(../../../Images/dropdownarrow.bmp);
                                            background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;" />
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="link1" runat="server"/>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>

                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>

                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:DataGrid>
```

I want to get the id of controls 'lstNo' and 'lstNo1' in my $(document).ready function, how to get the id of Listbox 'lstNo' and 'lstNo1' in $(document).ready function?

My itemtemplate contains more than one row, so using clientIDMode = 'static' will not get the id, Is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If it is in the aspx page then you can get it using **ClientID** property of control:

```
var Id = <%=lstNo.ClientID%>;
```

If you want to access in seperate JS file then you can use **ClientIDMode** to make it **Static** so that id on client side is same as on Server Side:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstNo" runat="server" DisplayMode="LinkButton" ClientIdMode="Static"
```

and now:

```
var Id = "lstNo";

$("#"+Id)
```

or directly use:

```
$("#lstNo")
```

Comment: when using '<%=lstNo.ClientID%>' it shows error on page load ''lstNo' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: refer this for that error:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178866/txtname-is-not-declared-it-may-be-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level 
and make sure you partial class is public

Comment: If the itemtemplate contains the listbox is repeatable, then how can i get the id?

Comment: Sorry i don't know about that

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the html rendering of DataGrid control. If it renders a html table markup, Then you would have to perform the looping of the rows of the html table and then pluck the control whose id contains "lstNo".

Please check what is the generated html output in the browser window by using the tool like firebug or do the view source in IE. I guess listbox render the dropdown in the form of the

```
<select> tag.
```